# Get argument description of excel worksheetfunctions in VSTO vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, vsto, add-in

I am trying to build a function that returns the description a built-in worksheetfunction's argument using worksheetfunction's name and field position as inputs.

```
GetExcelArgumentDescription("IF",1) should return "logical_test"
GetExcelArgumentDescription("IF",2) should return "value_if_true"
GetExcelArgumentDescription("IF",3) should return "value_if_false"
```

I have seen this in add-ins like [this one (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSyAs.png).

Is is possible to get this [argument description (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRGOY.png) via VSTO? How does the code look like in vb.net?

Comment: Are you after the formula in the cell, Excel built-in functions or user-defined functions?

Comment: I am after Excel built-in functions

Comment: For example, you want to pass a parameter of "ABS" and return "Returns the absolute value of a number"?

Comment: No. I am looking for the description of the argument fields. For example, ABS has a single argument and it is named 'number'. I have included a screenshot to make it fully clear

Comment: The worksheetfunction property of Excel is not an addressable collection.

Comment: I have seen one VSTO add-in doing this. There must be a way. I attach now a screenshot of this add-in.

Comment: They may be storing that information in a table. I got my last comment directly from Microsoft.

Comment: You are right. It could well be what you are saying. I found a full list of 471 worksheetfunctions in the office support website (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188). What is the optimal way to store such a table and query argument' descriptions from there?

Comment: I've used SQL Server CE, to store tables in my VSTO Addins

Comment: Here's an example in both VB.net and C# https://github.com/Office-projects/Script-Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `worksheetfunction` property of Excel is not an addressable collection.  You can create your own list from [Microsoft's listing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188). Then reference your own list.

Comment: No worries mate